# How to make a table wider than container in Firefox ESR 38

Tags: css, firefox

this is my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jpmolinamatute/pen/dRpwvb?editors=0100),

```
<div title="Monitor Table: Cluster Queue Status" data-type="livereport" data-title="Cluster Queue Status" class="u-monitor meter ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable" id="42DCmauenMCrxjZEb">
    <div class="meter-header">
      <div class="edge livereport">&nbsp;</div>
      <h4>Cluster Queue Status</h4>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle">
          <span class="sr-only">Options: livereport</span>
          <span class="icon icon-burger-small"></span>
        </button>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu with-arrow small align-right">
          <li>
            <div class="dropdown-content panels">
              <div class="panel-edit">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">


                  <li>
                    <button type="button" data-action="edit" class="btn-link link-with-icon icon-edit">
                      Edit
                    </button>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <button type="button" data-action="delete" class="btn-link link-with-icon icon-delete">Delete
                    </button>
                  </li>

                </ul>
                <hr>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li>
                    <button type="button" data-action="downloadPdf" class="btn-link">Download .pdf</button>
                  </li>
                  <!--<li>-->
                  <!--<button type="button" class="btn-link">Download .jpg</button>-->
                  <!--</li>-->
                  <!--<li>-->
                  <!--<button type="button" class="btn-link">Download .png</button>-->
                  <!--</li>-->

                    <li>
                      <button class="btn-link" data-action="downloadCSV" type="button">Download .csv</button>
                      <a style="display: none" id="downloadCSV" download="Cluster Queue Status.csv"></a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="right: auto; bottom: 5px; width:100%; overflow: auto;" class="u-monitor-container">

        <div style="display: none;" class="table-loading">
          <p>
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-fw"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="filter-list">

        </div>
        <table style="max-height: 346px;" class="table table-striped" data-type="report">
          <thead>
          <tr>

              <th data-key="cluster_name">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;cluster_name&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Cluster Name</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="name">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;name&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Queue Name</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="usedSlots">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;usedSlots&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Used Slots</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="availableSlots">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;availableSlots&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Available Slots</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="ambiguous">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;ambiguous&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Ambiguous</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="disabledByCalendar">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;disabledByCalendar&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Disabled By Calendar</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="disabledManual">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;disabledManual&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Disabled Manual</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="error">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;error&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Error</span>

                    <span class="th-button-sort">
                      <i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>
                    </span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="loadAlarm">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;loadAlarm&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Load Alarm</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="manualIntervention">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;manualIntervention&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Manual Intervention</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="orphaned">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;orphaned&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Orphaned</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="reservedSlots">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;reservedSlots&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Reserved Slots</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="suspendByCalendar">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;suspendByCalendar&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Suspend By Calendar</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="suspendManual">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;suspendManual&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Suspend Manual</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="suspendOnSubordinate">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;suspendOnSubordinate&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Suspend On Subordinate</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="suspendThreshold">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;suspendThreshold&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Suspend Threshold</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="tempDisabled">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;tempDisabled&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Temp Disabled</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="totalSlots">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;totalSlots&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Total Slots</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="unknown">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;unknown&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Unknown</span>

                </button>
              </th>

              <th data-key="load">
                <div class="blocker"></div>
                <button data-key="{&quot;mainAttr&quot;:&quot;load&quot;}" class="th-container" type="button">
                  <span class="th-button-title">Load</span>

                </button>
              </th>

          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody><tr><td>test charlie</td><td>queue-17.q</td><td>1754</td><td>8246</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>21.719</td></tr><tr><td>test charlie</td><td>queue-42.q</td><td>7226</td><td>2774</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>12.993</td></tr><tr><td>test charlie</td><td>queue-16.q</td><td>8469</td><td>1531</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>16.730</td></tr><tr><td>test charlie</td><td>queue-9.q</td><td>8639</td><td>1361</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>14.279</td></tr><tr><td>test charlie</td><td>queue-6.q</td><td>8584</td><td>1416</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>18.757</td></tr><tr><td>test charlie</td><td>queue-34.q</td><td>6280</td><td>3720</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>4.167</td></tr><tr><td>test charlie</td><td>queue-33.q</td><td>1839</td><td>8161</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>26.900</td></tr><tr><td>cluster 3</td><td>queue-10.q</td><td>3478</td><td>6522</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>1.511</td></tr><tr><td>cluster 3</td><td>queue-29.q</td><td>4918</td><td>5082</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>11.513</td></tr><tr><td>cluster 3</td><td>queue-28.q</td><td>4334</td><td>5666</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>25.730</td></tr><tr><td>cluster 3</td><td>queue-4.q</td><td>3960</td><td>6040</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>8.859</td></tr><tr><td>cluster 3</td><td>queue-24.q</td><td>4662</td><td>5338</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>19.812</td></tr><tr><td>cluster 3</td><td>queue-30.q</td><td>8255</td><td>1745</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>36.908</td></tr><tr><td>cluster 3</td><td>queue-11.q</td><td>5390</td><td>4610</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>2.718</td></tr><tr><td>UGE841</td><td>queue-2.q</td><td>8059</td><td>1941</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>37.822</td></tr><tr><td>UGE841</td><td>queue-43.q</td><td>7649</td><td>2351</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>29.769</td></tr><tr><td>UGE841</td><td>queue-8.q</td><td>784</td><td>9216</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>1.039</td></tr><tr><td>UGE841</td><td>queue-26.q</td><td>7183</td><td>2817</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>4.707</td></tr><tr><td>UGE841</td><td>queue-31.q</td><td>7089</td><td>2911</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>4.700</td></tr><tr><td>UGE841</td><td>queue-32.q</td><td>3501</td><td>6499</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10000</td><td>8</td><td>5.015</td></tr></tbody>

            <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="21">20 of 20</td>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>

        </table>

    </div>
    <div style="width: 0; height: 0;" class="click-receiver">
      <button style="display: none;" class="menu-hover" type="button"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
  </div>
```

this piece of html/css works just fine in modern version of chrome and firefox, but it doesn't in Firefox 38 which I need to support :-(

basically I have a container(main) position absolute with overflow auto width 100% relative to the parent container(grandparent). Inside the main container I have a table which in FF38 gets as wide as the main container and some parts of the columns get overlapped with each other. In modern browsers the table get wider than the container and you can see an scroll bar that allow you to move right/left.

so the question is how can I reproduce this behaviour on FF38??
thanks in advance :-)